# JS splice function to Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays, splice

The main goal is well, first. array a will contain more values than array b, a contains a,a,a,b,c,c,d,e and the b contains a,b,b,b,b,c,c,and I want to find the same values from array b in the array a, that would be a,b,b,b,b,c,c...every time find one item, I will link some events...but normally it will find the same value only once, that would be a,b,c...I don't want that.

This is my Js code:

```
    var a = ['he','you','and','she','me'];
    var b = ['he','and','you','and'];

    for(var i = 0;i < a.length;i++){
       for(var ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++){
          if(b[ii] == a[i]){
             b.splice(ii,1);
          }
     }
```

First, look through the items of array b in the array a, I want to remove the first of the double items in the array a, when the array b match with array a, and then look thorough again, then repeat the steps...
and I want to convert js code to objective-c, anyone knows how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want `a` to contain `['you','and']` and `b` to contain `['me']` afterwards?

Comment: can you add the expected output? What should b be contain in the end? I think you are making it far too complicated for yourself and splice is probably not even the easiest way to go

Comment: The main goal is matching the items of array b with the items of the array a, but if the array b has some same items itself, it will only match only once, i want to match more than once, it depends how many same items array b has...

Comment: still not clear - think up an example that includes every possible variation of input and tell us the exact desired output

Comment: if a contains a,a,a,b,c,c and b contains a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d,e - what should be the final result in b?

Comment: well, first. array a will contain more values than array b, a contains a,a,a,b,c,c,d,e and the b contains a,b,b,b,b,c,c,and I want to find the same values from array b in the array a, that would be a,b,b,b,b,c,c...every time find one item, I will link some events...but normally it will find the same value only once, that would be a,b,c...I don't want that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your splice function should do. But perhaps you could base it on the following snippet:

```
NSArray* result = [sourceArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];
```

Comment: So I understand given two arrays a1 and a2 the function should return an array that contains all items in a1 that are not in a2?

Comment: @ Rudi Angela, The main goal is matching the items of array b with the items of the array a, but if the array b has some same items itself, it will only match only once, i want to match more than once, it depends how many same items array b has...

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I haven't got the faintest idea what you really want. Maybe better to give a whole list of examples covering all possible cases, and then some more.